# Convert Non-Standard varchar to DATETIME

Tags: sql-server, datetime, type-conversion

I've got a non-standard datetime being passed to me into some of my SQL Server tables and hoping someone might have already done this so I don't have to re-invent the wheel here. I could probably spend some time tearing it apart with `SUBSTRING` and so on, but wondering if anyone has an elegant way or something that might help me here.

Examples:

```
Tue, 16 Mar 2021 16:04:59 GMT
Fri, 12 Mar 2021 00:00:16 GMT
```

So its something like...
day (garbage), dd mmm yyyy HH:MM:SS timezone (garbage)

Comment: if the format is fixed, you can simply `CONVERT(datetime, SUBSTRING([DateCol], 6, 20))` But you still handle the time zone separtely

Answer (score 0):

Eh, elegant is a stretch but this works :)

```
DECLARE @myDate varchar(50)
SET @myDate = 'Tue, 16 Mar 2021 16:04:59 GMT'

SELECT @myDate AS [myDate], CONVERT(DATETIME, LEFT(SUBSTRING(@myDate, 5, LEN(@myDate)), LEN(SUBSTRING(@myDate, 5, LEN(@myDate))) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@myDate, 5, LEN(@myDate)))))) AS [finalMyDate]
```

And this one takes the cake for simple and elegant! Thanks Squirrel

```
DECLARE @myDate varchar(50)
SET @myDate = 'Tue, 16 Mar 2021 16:04:59 GMT'

SELECT CONVERT(datetime, SUBSTRING(@myDate, 6, 20))
```